# Fedora Linux cannot boot after installing Oracle XE 18.4

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

I installed Oracle Express Edition 18.4 on Fedora Linux 29 using RPMs.

The installation went fairly well, except that I had to build the `compat-libcap1` RPM from source, as it is not shipped with Fedora 29.

Setup using `/etc/init.d/oracle-xe-18c configure` went without problems, and I could start, stop and use Oracle just fine.

I added `$ORACLE_HOME/lib` to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-xe-x86_64.conf` and ran `ldconfig` so that Oracle is on the library path for all executables.

But upon the next reboot, the machine didn't come up again. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a longer debugging session, it turned out that adding the library directory to the default library path was the problem.

Oracle provides a shared library `libexpat.so.1` that is also provided by the operating system, but is not binary compatible with it.

Now some executables required in the boot process (notably `/usr/bin/dbus-daemon`) require that shared library, and they failed to start with:

```
symbol lookup error: /usr/bin/dbus-daemon: undefined symbol: XML_SetHashSalt
```

Once I figured that out, the solution was simple: remove `$ORACLE_HOME/lib` from the default shared library path (and then run `ldconfig`).

Comment: `ldconfig` will need to be executed after removing `$ORACLE_HOME/lib`.

I ran into the exact same issue with CentOS 7 / Oracle 18 and gor here after searching for `XML_SetHashSalt`, which saved me a lot of head scratching.